# Calculating per-pixel mean rainfall values based on start and end of the season

Tags: r, select, stack, raster, r-raster

I have a RasterStack of 365 layers (R1998). Each layer represents one day of rainfall data (i.e., from 01/01 up to 31/12). Then, I have two rasterLayers that report, for each pixel, the day of the year when the growing season starts (SOS) and the day of the year when the growing season finishes (EOS):

```
> R1998
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 291, 327, 95157, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : -18.25, 63.5, -35, 37.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
values     : ...

> SOS
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 291, 327, 95157  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : -18.25, 63.5, -35, 37.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 365  (min, max)

> EOS
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 291, 327, 95157  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : -18.25, 63.5, -35, 37.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 365  (min, max)
```

I cannot figure out how to calculate, for each pixel, the mean rainfall value (and other metrics) only between the start and end of the growing season. For instance:

- pixel[1,1] has SOS=day97 and EOS=day128: calculate the mean rainfall between day 97 and day 128 of R1998.
- pixel[1,2] has SOS=day95 and EOS=day131: calculate the mean rainfall between day 95 and day 131 of R1998.
- pixel[1,3] has SOS=day81 and EOS=day110: calculate the mean rainfall between day 81 and day 110 of R1998.
- ...and so on for all pixels.

I cannot really implement this option within stackApply. I spent most of the time trying with stackSelect, but this just extracts the pixel value at the SOS/EOS position within R1998. I tried to transform the rasterStack to a data frame (rasterToPoint) but it gets messy.

I am sure this is straightforward, but I just cannot find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(This is part of the Liebmann climate metrics calculation; Liebmann et al., 2012 - Journal of Climate)

**Follow up question**: for each pixel, I now have to calculate the daily rainfall minus the mean annual rainfall (MAP; the per-pixel long-term mean) between SOS and EOS. For instance:

- Pixel[1,1] SOS=day97 and EOS=day128: calculate rain_day97 – MAP; rain_day98 – MAP; […]; rain_day128 – MAP
- Pixel[1,2] SOS=day95 and EOS=day131: calculate rain_day95 – MAP; rain_day96 – MAP; […]; rain_day131 – MAP
- …and so on for all pixels

**rapp** and **app** both return one value for each pixel (e.g., fun=mean returns the mean value between SOS and EOS), but here I need one value (rain_day – MAP) for each day between SOS and EOS (i.e., a list of files). **tapp** seems appropriate, but I find it hard to recycle the SOS/EOS indexes.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `terra` package has a method called `rapp` (range-apply) for this problem. You can do

```
x <- rapp(R1998, SOS, EOS, fun=mean)
```

Where the first three arguments are `SpatRaster` objects. You can create these with `terra::rast` from you Raster* objects, or from files.

Here is a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncol=9, nrow=9)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
rain <- c(r, r, r, r, r, r)
rain <- rain * 1:6
rain[1:2] <- NA
sos <- eos <- rast(r)
sos[] <- 1:3
eos[]   <- 4:6
```

Solution

```
r <- rapp(rain, sos, eos, fun="mean")
```

Solution for the follow up question:

```
MAP <- rain+10
r <- rapp(rain-MAP, sos, eos, fun="mean")
```

If you do not want to summarize, but keep all values between `sos` and `eos`, and set the others to `NA`, you can do

```
r <- rapp(rain-MAP, sos, eos, allyrs=TRUE)
```

But I now see a bug here ([fixed on github](https://github.com/rspatial/terra) in terra v1.1-18. In earlier versions you need to add 1 to `eos`

```
rr <- rapp(rain-MAP, sos, eos+1, allyrs=TRUE)
```

Comment: See my expanded answer. In the future please ask a new question or edit your question --- and include a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example. The comment section is not very good for this.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and suggestion, @Robert. **About the follow up:** rapp returns only one value (mean, sum, etc.). Is there a way to get a list of SpatRaster reporting *rain-MAP* calculated for each day between SOS and EOS? But actually, I guess the issues is that the number of days between SOS and EOS must be the same in all pixels then.

Comment: Will do @greybeard